# Compiler logic with Java Multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading

So I'm slightly confused as to how multi-threading works.  For example, if I create a subclass of `Thread` called `MySub`, and this is what it looks like:

```
public class MySub extends Thread {
   public void run {
      for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
         System.out.println(i); 
      }
   }
}
```

And in the main class I do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread m = new MySub();
    Thread m2 = new MySub();
    m.start();
    m2.start();
}
```

Shouldn't it call the `start()` method for `m`, and then go straight to calling the `start()` method for `m2`, without waiting for the `m` thread to finish? Isn't that the point of multithreading?

But in actuality, it prints 0 through 4 from the `start()` call for `m`, and then 0 through 4 for the `start()` call for `m2`. They didn't go concurrently, they went sequentially, which isn't what I expected. I kind of expected a mess of 0 through 4 numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a race condition @Jake.  Your `main` is *not* waiting for the first thread to finish before starting the second.    It is starting the first thread which finishes its work *before* `main` gets a chance to start the second thread.

If you tried printing (let's say) 1000 numbers or something that takes more time, you would start to see them interleave.  Or you could put a `Thread.sleep(10)` between your `println` statements which would show it more specifically.

FYI: it is recommended to have your classes `implement Runnable` as opposed to `extends Thread`.  Then you would do:

```
Thread m1 = new Thread(new MySub());
m1.start();
```

Also, use of the `ExecutorService` code is recommended more than using thread directly.